# What does size of the memcmp return value mean?

Tags: c, memcmp

I just happened to debug an incredibly nasty error: On my own PC (Windows 7 x64, MinGw) my C program would successfully sort an array using the `memcmp` when comparing array members.

My function used bubble sort algorithm and it's skeleton would look like this:

```
void array_sort(ArrayMap *array, char direction) {
    make sure direction is +1 or -1 only
    define some variables
    for(...) {
         for(...) {
             cmpres = memcmp(elm1, elm2, sizeOfElement);
             if (cmpres!=0&&cmpres!=direction)
             {
                 SWAP here
             }
         }
}
```

Now while on my PC, the `memcmp` has returned `-1`, `0` and `1` on another it returned `-5`, `0` and `5`. By comparing this with `direction` I caused the sorting to go totally wrong.

But I wonder, what does the absolute value (that is, the size) of the return value of `memcmp` actually mean?

From the [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/):

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   content of the memory blocks: A zero value indicates that the contents
>   of both memory blocks are equal. A value **greater than zero** indicates
>   that the first byte that does not match in both memory blocks has a
>   greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2 as if evaluated as unsigned char
>   values; And a value **less than zero** indicates the opposite.

No mention of the size, they just make sure not to be wrong about +-1 by saying *greater than zero*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result magnitude implementation-specific, so it has no portable meaning and you should not rely on it.  The `memcmp()` function is only guaranteed to return a positive, negative, or zero value.

The reason why it is allowed to have any value is so `memcmp()` can be defined like this:

```
// Types changed to "char" to simplify code.
int memcmp(const unsigned char *x, const unsigned char *y, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int diff = x[i] - y[i];
        if (diff)
            return diff;
}
```

But it can also be implemented by using, e.g., SSE, and the return value will be different.

Comment: Jun in case anyone wondered, [SSE is processor instruction set](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions).

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcmp.html) says:

> The memcmp() function shall return an integer greater than, equal to,
>   or less than 0, if the object pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal
>   to, or less than the object pointed to by s2, respectively.

It doesn't say it will return -1 or 1. What it exactly returns is implementation dependent.

**Update:**

When implementing a comparison function, you often write:

```
return a[i] - b[i];
```

Instead of:

```
if (a[i] > b[i])
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

That's one possible implementation that explains the numbers that are returned.